# What test is this for endogenous variables?

Tags: r, econometrics, causality, hausman

Can somebody tell me whether the following R code (for econometrics endogenous variables) is for a Hausman test, a Nakamura test, or some other test?

```
etudes1 <- lm(EDUC  ~ EXPER+EXPERSQ+SMSA+SOUTH+FATHEDUC+MOTHEDUC)

test    <- lm(LWAGE ~ EDUC+EXPER+EXPERSQ+SMSA+SOUTH +residuals(etudes1))
summary(test)
```

Comment: This is a two-stage least squares (2SLS) model. After you find the endogenous variables in your formula, you should use this model instead of an OLS model.

Answer (score 4):

What you have written *looks* like it could be the Hausman test, if $lwage$ was your main outcome of interest, $educ$ is your potentially endogenous predictor, and $feduc$ and $meduc$ are exogenous instruments (I'm not an R user, but that's what I gathered from your code, at least).

To recap, the Hausman test for endogeneity is carried out in two steps.  Given the model you are trying to estimate:

> $y_i =\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + Z\beta + u_i$

Where:

- $y_i$ = main outcome of interest
- and $x_i$ = endogenous predictor of interest
- and $Z$ = a vector of exogenous predictors

First, regress $x_i$ on $Z$ and our instrument(s) (let's call it $I$) and save $\hat\nu_i$:

> $x_i =\pi_0 + \pi_1I_i + Z\pi + \nu_i$
>
> Because $Z$ and $I$ are exogenous (uncorrelated with $u_i$), it stands
>   to reason that $x_i$ is uncorrelated with $u_i$ IFF $\nu_i$ is
>   uncorrelated with $u_i$ (our main predictor of interest $x_i$ is
>   **exogoneous** if and only if the two error terms are uncorrelated).  Therefore, we need to formally test whether these two error terms are correlated.

Second, run the Hausman test by regressing $y_i$ on $x_i$, $Z$, and $\hat\nu_i$:

> $y_i =\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + Z\beta + \delta\hat\nu_i + error$
>
> For this test $H_0: \delta=0$.  If the coefficient on $\hat\nu_i$--that is, $\delta$--is significant, we can conclude that $x_i$ was in fact endogenous because the two error terms **were**, in fact, correlated.

I imagine most statistical packages today have the Hausman test for endogeneity built-in.  What I have provided above is what used to be done manually "back in the day."

**Source:**
Wooldridge, J. 2003. *Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach*. 2nd ed. New York: Thomson Learning

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not provide the Hausman test for endogneity. The hausman.systemfit() from the [systemﬁt package in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/systemfit/systemfit.pdf) should do the trick.

Hope that helps.

FJA

Comment: Do you know what kind of test it is? (I think that might help the OP.)

Comment: +1, I think it would help the OP if you would put some of that into your answer & unpack it a little bit. Eg: how what is posted differs from the logic of (say) the Hausman test, etc., whether this test is likely to be useful / accurate, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In a next question I will post in a few minutes I will complete.