# Econometrics: Sargan test

Tags: r, econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

Here are 3 questions about econometrics and `R` codes.

Test the endogeneity of the variable EDUC:

```
etudes1 <- lm(EDUC ~ EXPER+EXPERSQ+SMSA+SOUTH+FATHEDUC+MOTHEDUC, data=Dataset)

Call:
lm(formula = LWAGE ~ EDUC + EXPER + EXPERSQ + SMSA + SOUTH + residuals(etudes1))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.73299 -0.21985  0.02344  0.24196  1.35879 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         3.9002276  0.1998339  19.517  < 2e-16 ***   
EDUC                0.1214847  0.0116061  10.467  < 2e-16 ***  
EXPER               0.1073102  0.0092801  11.563  < 2e-16 ***   
EXPERSQ            -0.0024888  0.0004016  -6.197 6.86e-10 ***   
SMSA                0.1355027  0.0193295   7.010 3.15e-12 ***   
SOUTH              -0.1311756  0.0178376  -7.354 2.70e-13 ***   
residuals(etudes1) -0.0463500  0.0123884  -3.741 0.000188 ***
---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.3811 on 2213 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.251,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.2489 
F-statistic: 123.6 on 6 and 2213 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

1. The "residuals" variable is significant (p-value = 0.000188), which
   means that we reject $H_{0}$: the variable EDUC is **not** EXOGENOUS.
   That means that we must use the 2SLS (instead of the OLS) to
   estimate the efficiency of the education (EDUC). Is it right?

**The Sargan Test**

```
Call:
lm(formula = residuals(iv1) ~ EXPER + EXPERSQ + SMSA + SOUTH + FATHEDUC + MOTHEDUC)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.90114 -0.23667  0.02866  0.24715  1.43550 

Coefficients: 
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -7.948e-03  5.472e-02  -0.145    0.885    
EXPER       -1.996e-04  8.019e-03  -0.025    0.980   
EXPERSQ      4.986e-06  4.113e-04   0.012    0.990   
SMSA         1.486e-03  1.907e-02   0.078    0.938    
SOUTH       -1.191e-04  1.771e-02  -0.007    0.995    
FATHEDUC    -3.054e-03  2.998e-03  -1.019    0.309    
MOTHEDUC     3.669e-03  3.548e-03   1.034    0.301

Residual standard error: 0.3907 on 2213 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.000607,   Adjusted R-squared: -0.002103 
F-statistic: 0.224 on 6 and 2213 DF,  p-value: 0.9691 

jour_sargan <- summary(sargan)  
r2iv   <- jour_sargan$r.square     # $
r2iv                               # [1] 0.0006070252    
obs    <- jour_sargan$r.square*500    
obs                                # [1] 0.3035126   
pvalue <- 1-pchisq(obs, df=1)    
pvalue                             # [1] 0.5816887
```

1. Do I have to look at the 2 p-values: FATHEDUC (p-value = 0.309) and
   MOTHEDUC (p-value = 0.301)? Or do I have to look at the final
   p-value of the Sargan Test (p=0.5816887) to take my final decision?
2. We don't reject $H_{0}$, so the instrumental variables (FATHEDUC and
   MOTHEDUC) are **not** EXOGENOUS. Is it right?

Comment: Readers may note also this previous, related question: [what-test-is-this-for-endogenous-variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61054/).